# How to make a video player fit its content?

Tags: html, css, video, overlay, video.js

I'm making a web application where a background video is the main feature.
I have managed to make the video fit the whole screen by getting some black bars on the sides to prevent the aspect ratio (i need the whole video to be shown I don't want parts cut off).

**This is what happens when the width is not enough**
[image]

**This is what happens when the height is not enough**
[image]

That's what I want it to do actually, there is only one issue. The message you can see on both pictures is from the plugin videojs-overlay that aligns messages where you want, in this case, top. And to align these messages it takes the whole viewport but not where the video is playing.

**I want this to happen**
[image]

**This is my actual code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video-js.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/7.5.4/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://players.brightcove.net/videojs-overlay/2/videojs-overlay.css" rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Videojs Dailymotion</title>
    <style>
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .videoContainer
    {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    }
    .videoContainer video
    {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    }
    .video-js .vjs-control-bar,
    .video-js .vjs-big-play-button,
    .video-js .vjs-menu-button .vjs-menu-content {
    /* IE8 - has no alpha support */
    background-color: #2B333F;
    /* Opacity: 1.0 = 100%, 0.0 = 0% */
    background-color: rgba(43, 51, 63, 0);
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin videoContainer" controls >
      <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1KhfURPSYOTjPVxIwWdicd5OHo651PaPy" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
    <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/videojs-overlay/2/videojs-overlay.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var player = videojs('vid1',{
    controls: true,
    posterImage: false,
    textTrackDisplay: false,
    loadingSpinner: false,
    controlBar: {
    fullscreenToggle: false,
    progressControl: false,
    remainingTimeDisplay: false
    }
    });
    player.overlay({
    content: '<strong>Default overlay content</strong>',
    overlays: [{
      align: "top",
      content: 'This event-triggered overlay message appears when the video is playing',
      start: 'play',
      end: 'pause'
    }]});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried object-fits, fluid aspectRatio and nothing seems to work
Another image to explain what I want to do:

**I want the blue square to be the red square while mainteining the aspect ratio**
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda got what i wanted in the end.

```
.container {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: red;
overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
width: 100%;
max-width: calc(100vh / 0.5625);
padding-bottom: (9 / 16) * 100%;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
background-color: deepskyblue;
}

<video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" style="width:100%;height:auto; position: relative;" controls>
      <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1KhfURPSYOTjPVxIwWdicd5OHo651PaPy" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
```

With this i was able to mantain the aspect ratio of the video while keeping the player on the video content.
The only problem is that the video is not centered on the screen.
THank everyone for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one.

```
.video-js.videoContainer video {
   display: block;
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 100%;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   z-index: 1;
   width: auto;
   height: auto;
}
```

Or maybe even this one on video element:

```
object-fit: cover;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not concerned with aspect ratio, then `object-fit: fill;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video-js.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.5.4/video.js"></script>
    <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/7.5.4/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://players.brightcove.net/videojs-overlay/2/videojs-overlay.css" rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Videojs Dailymotion</title>
    <style>
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }
    .videoContainer
    {
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
padding-top: 50%;
    }
    .videoContainer video
    {
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    object-fit: fill; /*Added property*/
    }
    .video-js .vjs-control-bar,
    .video-js .vjs-big-play-button,
    .video-js .vjs-menu-button .vjs-menu-content {
    /* IE8 - has no alpha support */
    background-color: #2B333F;
    /* Opacity: 1.0 = 100%, 0.0 = 0% */
    background-color: rgba(43, 51, 63, 0);
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video id="vid1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin videoContainer" controls >
      <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1KhfURPSYOTjPVxIwWdicd5OHo651PaPy" type="video/mp4">

    </video>
    <script src="https://players.brightcove.net/videojs-overlay/2/videojs-overlay.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var player = videojs('vid1',{
    controls: true,
    posterImage: false,
    textTrackDisplay: false,
    loadingSpinner: false,
    controlBar: {
    fullscreenToggle: false,
    progressControl: false,
    remainingTimeDisplay: false
    }
    });
    player.overlay({
    content: '<strong>Default overlay content</strong>',
    overlays: [{
      align: "top",
      content: 'This event-triggered overlay message appears when the video is playing',
      start: 'play',
      end: 'pause'
    }]});
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This would be perfect if it didnt cut part of the video. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Updated the answer. If you dont mind changing the aspect ratio, then you may try object-fit: fill;

Comment: Sure thats better than nothing, if nothing else appears this is the way i'll go. Thanks!

Comment: Glad that this might be of help to you =)

Comment: object-fit: cover; in my opinion fits better in this case. Cause video wont be stretched, breaking its looks.